# YTD and MTD in the same query

Tags: sql-server-2008

i have

```
create table 
    tbl(CustKey int, dt varchar(6), category varchar(20), amtbc int)
    insert into tbl values(2475,'201402','P',100) 
    insert into tbl values(2475,'201403','P',130) 
    insert into tbl values(2475,'201311','R',2056) 
    insert into tbl values(2475,'201312','R',978)
    insert into tbl values(2475,'201406','P',100) 
    insert into #tbl values(2475,'201406','R',410)   
    insert into tbl values(2475,'201401','P',200)     
    insert into #tbl values(2475,'201407','R',179)
    insert into tbl values(2475,'201404','P',100) 
    insert into #tbl values(2475,'201405','P',380) 
    insert into tbl values(2475,'201407','P',100)
    insert into #tbl values(2475,'201401','R',1377)
    insert into tbl values(9628,'201404','P',500) 
    insert into #tbl values(9628,'201405','P',500) 
    insert into tbl values(9628,'201402','P',500) 
    insert into #tbl values(9628,'201406','P',500)
    insert into tbl values(9628,'201401','P',500) 
    insert into #tbl values(9628,'201407','P',500) 
    insert into tbl values(9628,'201403','P',500)
```

> select * from tbl:

```
CustKey dt  category    amtbc
2475  201402    P        100
2475  201403    P        130
2475  201311    R        2056
2475  201312    R        978
2475  201406    P        100
2475  201406    R        410
2475  201401    P        200
2475  201407    R        179
2475  201404    P        100
2475  201405    P        380
2475  201407    P        100
2475  201401    R        1377
9628  201404    P        500
9628  201405    P        500
9628  201402    P        500
9628  201406    P        500
9628  201401    P        500
9628  201407    P        500
9628  201403    P        500
```

Then i have this select, which count SUM amtbc per custkey. per category, per dt(monthly)

> select  custkey, dt, sum (case when category in ('R') then amtbc else
>   0 end) as ostatnisuma,
>
> sum (case when category in ('P') then amtbc else 0 end) as
>   residencesuma from tbl group by custkey,dt order by CustKey,dt
>   which gives me this:

```
custkey dt  ostatnisuma residencesuma
2475    201311  2056         0
2475    201312  978          0
2475    201401  1377        200
2475    201402  0           100
2475    201403  0           130
2475    201404  0           100
2475    201405  0           380
2475    201406  410         100
2475    201407  179         100
9628    201401  0           500
9628    201402  0           500
9628    201403  0           500
9628    201404  0           500
9628    201405  0           500
9628    201406  0           500
9628    201407  0           500
```

So now i know the amounts for each month. But id like to know for category P amount for every month(its ok) but for category R i want to know the amount in whole year, and enter this amount for whole year into every row for that year. so the final table will look like:

```
custkey dt  ostatnisuma residencesuma
2475  201311    2056       0
2475  201312    978        0
2475  201401    1377    1110
2475  201402    0       1110
2475  201403    0       1110
2475  201404    0       1110
2475  201405    0       1110
2475  201406    410     1110
2475  201407    179     1110
9628  201401    0       3500
9628  201402    0       3500
9628  201403    0       3500
9628  201404    0       3500
9628  201405    0       3500
9628  201406    0       3500
9628  201407    0       3500
```

Note that in reality, the number of categories is like 100+ and about 500 000 values... Thank you very much in advance for you help

Comment: i tried overpartition but it took forever...:/ then i tried things like "case when category = 'P' and LEFT(dt,4) = left(dt,4) then SUM(AmtBC) else 0 end as residencesumapokus " but it didnt work

Comment: then i tried  "(select SUM(amtbc) from  #tbl where category = 'P' and LEFT(dt,4) = left(dt,4)) as residencesumapokus" but it gives me the SUM of all 'P' , no matter the year :/

Comment: then i tried "(select isnull(SUM(amtbc),0) from  #tbl a where category = 'P' and LEFT(a.dt,4) = left(payments.dt,4)) as residencesumapokus" but it will duplicate rows :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [SUM YTD and MTD in the same query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25501166/sum-ytd-and-mtd-in-the-same-query)

Answer (score 1):

You want the OVER clause:

```
SUM(...) OVER (PARTITION BY custkey, dt/100)
```

Comment: Hi as i told before, in may case over partition is not possible due to a huge amount of values ( 100+categories etc) so the query will took forever...:/ but thanks for answer :)

Comment: You just need a proper index. Make a computed column on dt/100 (maybe call it dt100), and index (custkey, dt100). If you "include" all the other columns you need to return it should be very quick. You'll probably notice the query plan (without the index) has an expensive Sort. That Sort should disappear with the right index.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a `left join` on a query that groups by the customer key and year.

```
declare @tbl table (CustKey int, dt varchar(6), category varchar(20), amtbc int);
insert into @tbl values(2475,'201402','P',100) 
insert into @tbl values(2475,'201403','P',130) 
insert into @tbl values(2475,'201311','R',2056) 
insert into @tbl values(2475,'201312','R',978)
insert into @tbl values(2475,'201406','P',100) 
insert into @tbl values(2475,'201406','R',410)   
insert into @tbl values(2475,'201401','P',200)     
insert into @tbl values(2475,'201407','R',179)
insert into @tbl values(2475,'201404','P',100) 
insert into @tbl values(2475,'201405','P',380) 
insert into @tbl values(2475,'201407','P',100)
insert into @tbl values(2475,'201401','R',1377)
insert into @tbl values(9628,'201404','P',500) 
insert into @tbl values(9628,'201405','P',500) 
insert into @tbl values(9628,'201402','P',500) 
insert into @tbl values(9628,'201406','P',500)
insert into @tbl values(9628,'201401','P',500) 
insert into @tbl values(9628,'201407','P',500) 
insert into @tbl values(9628,'201403','P',500)

--select * from @tbl

select 
    t.CustKey, 
    t.dt, 
    sum (case when t.category in ('R') then t.amtbc else 0 end) as ostatnisuma,
    --sum (case when t.category in ('P') then t.amtbc else 0 end) as residencesuma,
    coalesce(avg(x.residencesuma),0) as residencesuma
from @tbl t 

-- sub-query totals custkey, year
left join(
    select 
        custkey, 
        left(dt,4) as year,
        sum (case when category in ('P') then amtbc else 0 end) as residencesuma
    from @tbl 
    where category in ('P') 
    group by custkey, left(dt,4)
) x on x.CustKey = t.CustKey and x.year = left(t.dt,4)

group by t.CustKey, t.dt 
order by t.CustKey, t.dt
```